# Cesium: Rotate around an entity

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

In cesium.js, how to make the camera rotate around an entity? I have tried screenSpaceCameraController.enableRotate, but it did not work. Does anyone know the solutions? Appreciately.

Comment: Or rotate around a selected point?

Comment: What means "Did not work". Share you code please.

Comment: Try double-clicking the entity, or set `viewer.trackedEntity =` to the entity.